# Unityのスクリプトでエラーが出ます

Tags: unity3d

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ScrollObject : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 1.0f;
    public float startPosition;
    public float endPosition;

    void Update() {
        //毎フレームｘポジションを少しずつ移動させる
        transform.Translate(-1 * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        //スクロールが目標ポイントまで到達したかをチェック
        if (transform.position.x <= endPosition) ScrollEnd();
    }

    void ScrollEnd() {
        //スクロールする距離分を戻す
        transform.Translate(-1 * (endPosition - startPotion), 0, 0);
        //毎ゲームオブジェクトにアタッチされているコンポーネントにメッセージを送る
        SendMessage("onScrollEnd", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
    }
}
```

エラー：

```
Assets/Script/ScrollObject.cs(21,56): error CS0103: The name `startPotion' does not exist in the current context
Assets/Script/ScrollObject.cs(21,27): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Transform.Translate(float, float, float)' has some invalid arguments
Assets/Script/ScrollObject.cs(21,27): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `object' expression to type `float'
```

Comment: `startPotion` は `startPosition` の間違いではないでしょうか…

Answer (score 3):

ScrollObject.csの21行目にあるstartPotionの綴りが間違っています。
startPositionと書き換えることでエラーは消えると思います。

エラーの対応方法がわからない場合、下記を試してみてください。

1. エラーは英語のメッセージですが、分からなければgoogle翻訳などで日本語にしてみてください。

   - 原文：The name `startPotion' does not exist in the current context
   - 翻訳：名前` startPotion 'は現在のコンテキスト内に存在しません
2. エラーをダブルクリックするとエディタの該当行へ移動します。上記エラーメッセージを意識してよく見直してみてください。
3. それでも意味がわからない場合、Googleでエラーメッセージを調べてみると同じエラーで苦労した人の解決策が見つかるかもしれません。